# How can i check whether there are any task scheduled under my user Id

Tags: windows-7, scheduled-tasks

How can i check whether there are any task scheduled under my user Id , also if there are any task scheduled , then how can i chnage the password for that.

The reason i am asking this question as there are issues like account lockout Out , where user is not aware of the password which he's using and due to that he ends up  by entering wrong password and get himself lockut out.

So we can go to the the task scheduler and can check how the password can be changed to see that this issue (Account lockout) can be minimized

Comment: Can you clarify the relationship that you perceive between scheduled tasks and passwords?  … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 0):

From an administrative command prompt:

```
schtasks /query /v
```

(The `/v` gives verbose output.)

Then look under the Run As User column. I find it helps to pipe the output to a text file, and then open it with an editor. Something like this:

```
schtasks /query /v > C:\Temp\SchTasksList.txt
```

This will tell you if there are any scheduled tasks running under the user ID in question.